# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Electrical Engineering's [fifth moderator election](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: SamGibson]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4964676350771200/0).

Comment: WTG SAM it’s harder than work and I expect you will do well.

Comment: @Tony Thanks! I knew that the mods (and CMs) did a lot "behind the scenes", but now I'm there, I'm seeing just how much work there is to do and also how much there is to learn (mod processes and tools etc.). I will do my best to help keep things running smoothly :-)

Answer (score 14):

Welcome to the moderation team, I think Sam will do a good job. It will also be great to have a moderator in the UK time zone.

Comment: Thanks very much! Now I've got to "learn the tools" and then start to add some value.  I look forward to working with you! Thanks again :-)

Comment: Yeah, if you have any questions let me know (chat works), there definitely is a learning curve

Answer (score 10):

Congrats and welcome Sam. :)

Please don't migrate questions off without consideration base on simple keywords or a hatred of noobs or arduino ;)

Comment: Although I had a concern about your candidacy (as you are well aware), this is a magnanimous post and I don't understand why it is attracting downvotes. I, for one, have upvoted it. You may find it hard to believe but I do not wish to have enmity between us -- I hope we can move forward with no hard feelings.

Comment: Passerby - Hi and thanks! I know you are concerned about migrations. When I have learned how to do them (!) I promise that I will carefully consider where the OP is most likely to get the best answers. For example, I have nothing against Arduino. I expect that questions which are *only* about using / installing / configuring the Arduino *framework* will be better suited to the Arduino part of SE. Whereas Arduino hardware-related questions are more likely to "stay here". OK so far? I know we're in different TZ, but I'm happy to listen to your concerns in chat (main chat room or a separate one).

Comment: I recognize that in the first month of my moderation I might have moved a few posts before I'd figured out what is going on. If you see any bad migrations in the last 60 days, please list them and why.

Answer (score 6):

As a Brit myself, great to have a mod in this time zone, plus, I vividly remember SamGibson going out of his way to help me with an issue I had, and I know personally another user I went to college with that they have also helped out, once again way beyond the help expected so with that kind of approach and willingness to really help, I think you will make a great addition to the moderation team.

Also, we share a surname, so that gives you bonus points from me!

Comment: Hi MCG - Thanks *very* much for the welcome :-) I remember that chat session! I will be trying to help keep things running smoothly, along with the rest of the mods. Hope things are going well with you.

Comment: @SamGibson Yeah, all good with me! fortunately been busy over the last few months, hope you are all good too. And congratulations again!